# Absolute positioned element not displaying based on its parent

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a dropdown menu using the `nested unordered lists`. Actually I'm having a parent unordered list which is having some `<li>` contains the first level menus. and i tried to insert `unordered lists` inside those first level menus i.e] inside those `<li>`. well i positioned the internal unordered list as `absolute` and i assigned `left` for them as 0.

And here comes the problem, The internal unordered list's parent should be the `<li>` element. But it assumes its parent as the main unordered list i.e] the parent of the `<li>` element. As a result the internal unordered list displays to the left of 0 with relative to the main unordered list. My need is to display it relative to the `<li>` element. What i am doing wrong .? why did that internal unordered list not assuming its parent as `<li>` element.?

### [DEMO - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEQkj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parent `li`'s style to:

```
#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li {
    /*Other styles*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hey, it really works..! Can you explain why did we need to set its position as relative.? so that i could correct this in future.?

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css

```
#ULHeaderMenuWrapperMenuCollection > li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
```

set `position: relative;` in parent li

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VEQkj/1/)